# Extract the integer part from a real valued variable in AceGen

Tags: acegen

I would like to extract the integer part of a real variable. To be more specific, given a vector `alpha` I would like to extract the integer part of `(||alpha||+Pi)/(2*Pi)`:

```
Get["AceGen`"];

SMSInitialize["GetFloor", "Language" -> "C"]; 
SMSModule["GetFloor", Real[alpha$$[3], floor$$]]; 
α ⊨ Table[SMSReal[alpha$$[i]], {i, 1, 3}]; 

GetFloor[α_] := Module[
  {normα},
  normα ⊨ SMSSqrt[α . α];
  SMSInteger[IntegerPart[N[normα + Pi/(2*Pi)]]]
];

SMSExport[GetFloor[α], floor$$]; 
SMSWrite[];

FilePrint["GetFloor.c"];
```

I checked in the C code produced and the instruction IntegerPart seems skipped by Acegen.

Is what I am trying to do possible at all in AceGen ? If so, what would be the syntax ?

Comment: Perhaps the documentation for `AceGen` could help?

Comment: The IntegerPart is a Mathematica function and will be evaluated at the time when you call your Module. It cannot be transfered to C code. If you define a variable as an integer i.e. n\[DoubleRightTee]SMSInteger[...], the integer part of a real value will be taken and should be visible in your generated C code as iXXX=(int)V[...].  Also n has to be defined in both branches of SMSIF by using the appropriate equal AceGen signs (se help for SMSIf) or if you use inline IF: n\[DoubleRightTee]SMSIF[...];

Comment: @MarcoMag Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: @MarcoMag I have edited the code in your question for readability. I hope it still conveys your intention?
I think your AceGen syntax is not correct, but maybe there are other ways to achieve your goals. I suggest that you expand your question with a more complete minimal working example and some additional explanation.

Comment: @Pinti thanks for the suggestion. I modified the question. Regarding the formatting of the code, I followed the instructions given [here](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-copy-code-from-mathematica-so-it-looks-good-on-this-site) but without success

Comment: @MarcoMag Thank you for adding a complete minimal example. For nice formatting of special symbols (Greek letters, AceGen operators, etc) you need some additional [tools](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1044/42046). Don't worry they are easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

The function `SMSFloor[]` seems to do the job. 
Here is the code:

```
Get["AceGen`"];

SMSInitialize["GetFloor", "Language" -> "C", "Mode" -> "Debug"];
SMSModule["GetFloor", Real[alpha$$[3], floor$$]];

α ⊨ Table[SMSReal[alpha$$[i]], {i, 1, 3}];

GetFloor[α_] := Module[
  {normα}, 
  normα ⊨ SMSSqrt[α.α];
  SMSFloor[normα/(2*Pi) + 1/2]
]

SMSExport[GetFloor[α], floor$$];
SMSWrite[];

FilePrint["GetFloor.c"];
```

Comment: Are you sure that this code really works? Because `FilePrint` shows suspiciously short C subroutine.
I think AceGen doesn't play nicely with local symbols in `Module`. (?)

Comment: @Pinti: My bad, I did not test the C code produced. The answer that was suggested lead to incorrect result despite the fact that AceGen did not throw any error. The value return was always `(*floor)=floor(0.13894156133957242e1);`. However, putting `normα` outside `N[]` seems to solve the problem.

Comment: Good job! In fact you can omit `N` function at all, because AceGen knows it has to convert it to real number.